# Application name as gradle parameter

Tags: android, gradle

I want to do something like that: `gradle build DemoApp`, and have DemoApp.apk with application name "DemoApp" as output.
Also, can I change application icon if with the same flow?
And some inner parameters?
Product flavors - not a secret for me. I do not need different configurations, I need to change application name at the build time. For example, I have some Rest API, that allows to pass parameter and return apk with application named as that parameter. The same with icon and other.

Comment: Can you please check the answers?

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [Manifest Merger](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Placeholder-support) specifically placeholders. Below is an example of setting the app name in gradle file.

```
// AndroidManifest.xml
<application
    android:label="${applicationName}"

// build.gradle
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        manifestPlaceholders = [applicationName: "MobileWorkforce"]
    }
```

The other option is to use @string/app_name and define different string.xml files based upon buildType/flavor.

Comment: I need build-time configuration, not prebuild configurations.

Comment: Then use gradle to supply a value besides a static string.

Answer (score 3):

Given that you don't know how to use flavours properly, a mix of other solutions.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:label="${applicationName}"
```

MyHttpThing.java

```
callserver(BuildConfig.ENDPOINT + "/api/v3/", "stuff")
```

build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        manifestPlaceholders = [applicationName: myappname]
        buildConfigField "String", "ENDPOINT", myendpoint
    }
```

and call with

```
gradle -Pmyappname=namy_name_name -Pmyendpoint="http://google.com" build DemoApp
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for [Product Flavors](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants), they're exactly for having multiple customized versions of the app with shared codebase. You can customize the icon, as long as any other resource. And yes, the .apk will be named according to the name of the flavor.

Comment: Ok then the answer by @MLProgrammer-CiM looks promising